# Xcode 5 can open my project but Xcode 6 crashes while trying to open

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

My iOS project opens perfectly with Xcode 5 and compiles, creates archive without any problem. But whenever I am trying to open with Xcode 6, Xcode 6 crashes with following messages:

Thanks in advance.

> -------------------- Process:         Xcode [1017] Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         6.0.1 (6528) Build Info:
>   IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2 App Item ID:     497799835 App
>   External ID: 712682811 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent
>   Process:  launchd [159] Responsible:     Xcode [1017] User ID:
>   501
>
> Date/Time:       2014-11-02 21:13:51.442 +0000 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.9.5 (13F34) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID: 
>   5E5B0875-B070-6EBF-492E-D372827F5E5D
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID: 535E2FC5-33F7-4221-BB5C-BE6A3D2EF7EA
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 6A317 ASSERTION
>   FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6245/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/ProjectModel/Xcode3Model/Xcode3Target.m:1206
>   Details:  fileReference should be an instance inheriting from
>   Xcode3FileReference, but it is 
>   Object:    Method:   -linkedBinaries
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1} Hints:
>   None Backtrace:   0  0x0000000109ae3f0a -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)   1  0x000000010889fbaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   2  0x000000010889fe9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   3  0x0000000112e4314c -[Xcode3Target linkedBinaries]
>   (in DevToolsCore)   4  0x0000000113284353 +[Xcode3UpgradeUnitTesting
>   analyzeInContext:] (in Xcode3UI)   5  0x00000001092e1a51 analyzeTasks
>   (in IDEFoundation)   6  0x00000001092e167f
>   IDEUpgradeTask_AllUpgradeTasksForContainer (in IDEFoundation)   7 
>   0x0000000112e373b3 -[Xcode3Project _runUpgradeChecksIfNecessary] (in
>   DevToolsCore)   8  0x0000000112e37900 -[Xcode3Project
>   enumerateUpgradeTasksWithBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)   9 
>   0x0000000109374e90 -[IDEWorkspaceUpgradeTasksController
>   processUpgradeTasks] (in IDEFoundation)  10  0x00007fff956be745
>   -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)  11  0x00007fff9569df31 -[**NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)  12  0x00007fff9569dbdb __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)  13 
>   0x00007fff8c9e128d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)  14
>   0x00007fff8c9e8ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)  15  0x00007fff8ea084f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** (in CoreFoundation)  16  0x00007fff8e9c3714 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)  17 
>   0x00007fff8e9c2e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)  18 
>   0x00007fff8caf3a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)  19 
>   0x00007fff8caf37b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)  20 
>   0x00007fff8caf35bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
>   (in HIToolbox)  21  0x00007fff8d88e24e _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)  22 
>   0x00007fff8d88d89b -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)  23 
>   0x0000000108e0c7bd -[DVTApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)  24 
>   0x00007fff8d88199c -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  25 
>   0x00007fff8d86c783 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  26 
>   0x00007fff8eff25fd start (in libdyld.dylib)   abort() called
>
> Application Specific Signatures: [(id)(fileReference)
>   isKindOfClass:[Xcode3FileReference class]]
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff95b73866 **pthread_kill + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181635c pthread_kill + 92
>   2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff92f88b1a abort + 125 3
>
>   com.apple.dt.IDEKit           0x0000000109ae3ae6 +[IDEAssertionHandler
>   _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:]
>   + 1510 4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit           0x0000000109ae40c0 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   + 1169 5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x000000010889fbaf _DVTAssertionHandler + 367 6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x000000010889fe9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407 7
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000112e4314c -[Xcode3Target
>   linkedBinaries] + 450 8   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI
>
>   0x0000000113284353 +[Xcode3UpgradeUnitTesting analyzeInContext:] + 359
>   9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation        0x00000001092e1a51 analyzeTasks +
>   432 10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation        0x00000001092e167f
>   IDEUpgradeTask_AllUpgradeTasksForContainer + 3816 11 
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000112e373b3 -[Xcode3Project
>   _runUpgradeChecksIfNecessary] + 1074 12  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore     0x0000000112e37900 -[Xcode3Project enumerateUpgradeTasksWithBlock:] +
>   73 13  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation     0x0000000109374e90
>   -[IDEWorkspaceUpgradeTasksController processUpgradeTasks] + 390 14  com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff956be745 -[NSBlockOperation
>   main] + 75 15  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff9569df31
>   -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631 16  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff9569dbdb __NSOQSchedule_f + 64 17  libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff8c9e128d _dispatch_client_callout + 8 18  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x00007fff8c9e8ef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333 19 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8ea084f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9 20  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8e9c3714 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1636 21  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 22  com.apple.HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8caf3a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226 23 
>   com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff8caf37b7
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479 24  com.apple.HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff8caf35bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   65 25  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8d88e24e _DPSNextEvent
>   + 1434 26  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff8d88d89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122 27  com.apple.dt.DVTKit           0x0000000108e0c7bd -[DVTApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237 28 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8d88199c -[NSApplication run]
>   + 553 29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d86c783 NSApplicationMain + 940 30  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff8eff25fd start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b73e6a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff95b74662 kevent64 + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e3421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
>   + 239 2   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e3136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b73e6a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b73e6a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 
>     0x00007fff95b6fa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6ed18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8e9c3f15 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8e9c3539 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff956fcff7 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
>   348 6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff956fcdfb
>   __NSThread__main** + 1318 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899 _pthread_body + 138 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b73e6a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b73e6a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 8:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b739aa __select + 10 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8ea0fa03 __CFSocketManager + 867 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899 _pthread_body + 138 3
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137
>   4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 9:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control File Path Processesing
>   Queue 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95b6fa56
>   semaphore_wait_trap + 10 1   libsystem_platform.dylib
>     0x00007fff8d300451 _os_semaphore_wait + 16 2   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff8c9e7982 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 310 3
>   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x00000001088d7b35 DVTDispatchSync + 30
>   4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation        0x0000000109423b4b
>   __60-[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor _startScanningWorkspace:]_block_invoke_2 + 1244 5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x00000001088d7bac
>   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 106 6   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e41bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 7
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e128d
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8 8   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e3673 _dispatch_queue_drain + 451 9   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff8c9e49c1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110 10  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x00007fff8c9e2f87 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75 11 
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8c9e4177
>   _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91816ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff95b6fa1a
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6ed18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8e9c3f15 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8e9c3539 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff956ff16c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
>   6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase     0x00000001142121d2
>   -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 676 7   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff956fcdfb __NSThread__main** +
>   1318 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899
>   _pthread_body + 138 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff95b6fa1a
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6ed18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8e9c3f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8e9c3539 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff8da2e05e _NSEventThread + 144 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91815899 _pthread_body + 138 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 12:: DYMobileDeviceManager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6fa1a mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6ed18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8e9c3f15 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8e9c3539 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff956ff16c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
>   6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff957e7b3a
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74 7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation   0x000000011710b9eb
>   -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134 8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff956fcdfb __NSThread__main** +
>   1318 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899
>   _pthread_body + 138 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff95b6fa1a
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff95b6ed18 mach_msg + 64 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8e9c3f15 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8e9c3539 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1161 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8e9c2e75
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309 5   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8ea78811 CFRunLoopRun + 97 6   com.apple.DebugSymbols
>     0x00007fff8ee8a7e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899 _pthread_body + 138 8
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137
>   9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 14: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff95b73a3a
>   __semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff92fa7dc0 nanosleep + 200 2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication
>   0x00007fff92d0a481 cleaner_thread_main(void*) + 42 3
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91815899 _pthread_body + 138 4
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff9181572a _pthread_start + 137
>   5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff91819fc9 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff7bf6a310  rcx: 0x00007fff5752ac38 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5752ac60  rsp: 0x00007fff5752ac38
>   r8: 0x0000000000003fff   r9: 0xffff80718ebe8c9f  r10:
>   0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x00007fff8f22d0d0 
>   r13: 0x00007f8e751fb800  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15:
>   0x00007f8e71417900   rip: 0x00007fff95b73866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206 
>   cr2: 0x000000011ad82000    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
>   0x02000148 Trap Number:     133

Comment: I had a similar problem. Solved it over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42186174/159991 hope it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Thomax! In my case there was a problem the way it was consuming/calling a web service. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to Uninstall and install Xcode 6

Comment: Thanks Suresh! I did but still not working! And if I take the whole project in any other Mac computer or laptop the problem persists. Xcode 6 crashes in all other Mac or laptop too. Seems, the problem is inside the project file. Thanks anyway.