# XCode 8 crashes when opening a project EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) and EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Macos Sierra. Xcode 8. I can open some projects, but a particluar project causes XCode to crash on start. Every time.

Below is the first 200 lines of the xcode crash log. Any insight at all would be extremely helpful!

```
Process:               Xcode [9299]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.0 (11246)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11246000000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       818744938
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [9299]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-09-20 22:54:14.003 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        65E7F980-9736-1A76-7A57-2CFD2AFC0DA7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       3D0C2E4A-A630-4295-8244-634B1C62A726

Time Awake Since Boot: 3100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: __42-[IBPlatformToolRequester processRequests]_block_invoke.235
ProductBuildVersion: 8A218a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-11201/Foundation/Utilities/IBFoundationAdditions.m:581
Details:  The input arrays must have the same length: (null), (
    "<NSImage 0x7f84520e5290 Size={60, 60} Reps=(\n    \"<NSCGImageSnapshotRep:0x7f8453027960 cgImage=<CGImage 0x7f8452053500>\\n\\t<<CGColorSpace 0x7f8448d3bfa0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>\\n\\t\\twidth = 60, height = 60, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 240 \\n\\t\\tkCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGImageByteOrder32Little \\n\\t\\tis mask? No, has mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? No>\"\n)>"
)
Function: void IBEnumerateParallelArrays(NSArray *__strong, NSArray *__strong, __strong IBParallelArrayIterator)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8448d16230>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   IBEnumerateParallelArrays (in IBFoundation)
  4  0x0000000122585775 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x0000000122583bfc (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6   -[IBSceneUpdateProcessingRequest processResult:orError:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
  7   -[IBSceneUpdateProcessingRequestGroup processProcessingResultsFromSceneUpdateResult:orDeliverError:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
  8   __37-[IBSceneUpdateManager _updateScene:]_block_invoke.401 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9   -[IBPlatformToolRequest runCompletionBlock] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10   -[IBPlatformToolRequester processResults] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 12   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 13   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 14   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 15   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 16   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 17   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 18   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 19   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 20   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 21   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 22   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 23   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 24   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
[arrayA count] == [arrayB count]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d7dda __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1c2797 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffba03d440 abort + 129
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ffe4c9d +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1466
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ffe5809 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1087
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e9555ac _DVTAssertionHandler + 475
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e955808 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 411
7   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x00000001197a5a6b IBEnumerateParallelArrays + 609
8   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x0000000122585775 0x1224a7000 + 911221
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x0000000122583bfc 0x1224a7000 + 904188
10  com.apple.dt.IBAutolayoutFoundation 0x0000000118bc539e -[IBSceneUpdateProcessingRequest processResult:orError:] + 127
11  com.apple.dt.IBAutolayoutFoundation 0x0000000118c16cb1 -[IBSceneUpdateProcessingRequestGroup processProcessingResultsFromSceneUpdateResult:orDeliverError:] + 823
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000121cbb17c __37-[IBSceneUpdateManager _updateScene:]_block_invoke.401 + 1554
13  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000121b01917 -[IBPlatformToolRequest runCompletionBlock] + 453
14  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000121b02e98 -[IBPlatformToolRequester processResults] + 823
15  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e9aaf12 ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke + 175
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f893ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f6a424 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f69ba5 __CFRunLoopRun + 917
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f695b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa450af6c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa450aca9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa450abd6 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa2c015f5 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa33118eb -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
25  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010ef010a8 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 396
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa2bf5fbd -[NSApplication run] + 926
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa2bc0a8a NSApplicationMain + 1237
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffb9fa9255 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d84e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf7c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d84e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf7c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d84e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf7c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d041a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0cf867 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f6a8d4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f69d61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f695b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa6966cb2 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011a3a4317 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1063
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa697730d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfabb _pthread_body + 180
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfa07 _pthread_start + 286
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf231 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d7f4e __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4fa572a __CFSocketManager + 682
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfabb _pthread_body + 180
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfa07 _pthread_start + 286
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf231 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d7c8a __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1c097a _pthread_cond_wait + 712
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fffb8b4e58d std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 47
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fffa7dc16dc void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 108
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fffa7dc165b bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 155
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fffa7dc1529 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*) + 9
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fffa7dc17dd void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 93
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfabb _pthread_body + 180
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfa07 _pthread_start + 286
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf231 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d041a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0cf867 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f6a8d4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f69d61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa4f695b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fffa413f144 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 313
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa697730d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfabb _pthread_body + 180
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bfa07 _pthread_start + 286
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf231 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: IDE Source Control File Path Processesing Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d83b6 __ulock_wait + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f8ba8e _dispatch_ulock_wait + 40
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f8bc6e _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 85
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f7e5ea _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 402
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f7f10f _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_recurse + 75
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e9a7bcd DVTDispatchSync + 169
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010f76d016 __60-[IDESourceControlWorkspaceMonitor _startScanningWorkspace:]_block_invoke_2 + 1345
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e9a7f4b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 827
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f7bf5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f73128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f89b97 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 896
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f7bd41 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1046
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f74ee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f74cb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:: Dispatch queue: -[IDEExecutionEnvironment initWithWorkspaceArena:] :: NSOperation 0x7f8450c1abc0 (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffba0d7c8a __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1c097a _pthread_cond_wait + 712
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa6a3b9fe -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 118
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa6a0b92c -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 310
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e8536f9 -[DVTOperationGroup main] + 67
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa6986d84 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 672
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e8536ab -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 111
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa6982c3b __NSOQSchedule_f + 201
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f73128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f89b97 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 896
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f7bd41 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1046
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f74ee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb9f74cb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffba1bf221 start_wqthread + 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the feeling this crash was caused by a `.xib` file which contained data no longer compatible with the new version of XCode. So I:

1. Removed half of the `.xib` file content
2. Saved the `.xib` file
3. Started XCode

If it still crashed, I proceeded to remove half of the data that remained. If it did not crash, I reasoned that the borked data must be in the other half. Repeated steps 1 to 3 until no more XCode crash.

This method worked. The following data was the cause of the crash in my `.xib`:

```
<navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Custom Content" id="314">
  <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" title="Edit" id="315">
    <connections>
      <action selector="editBookmarks:" destination="263" id="318"/>
    </connections>
  </barButtonItem>
</navigationItem>
```

I removed the `<barButtonItem .../>` element inside `<navigationItem .../>` and XCode did not crash anymore. Phew!

My conclusion is that `barButtonItem` used to be allowed inside `navigationItem` in an earlier version of Xcode, but the new version fails to migrate the content of the `.xib` and has no graceful way of warning, so it crashes hard.

If you get the same error as I did, check your `xib`s for `barButtonItem` nested inside `navigationItem`, delete them and add whatever was inside anew using the GUI.

If nested `barButtonItem` is *not* what's causing your crash you'll have to repeat my brute force method on your `xib`s until you single out the faulty xml code in your particular project. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

Delete the .xcworkspace file.
run pod install again to recreate the .xcworkspace file.

worked for me.

Comment: where is that file? what is it?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try to delete content from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

because your old application is referencing to other location.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out! I deleted all content in that folder, but same crash (and crash log).

Comment: it works for me. Only remove the folders with the name of my project and leave the others. I was open 2 projects with the same name

Comment: Hi @PrabhatPankaj, please see my alternative answer which worked for me. thanks.

Comment: @EyalBenYehuda yeah, I eventually solved it. See my answer.