# Xcode not working - how do I fix it?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am getting this error:

> Xcode was unexpectedly truncated.

Error detail:

```
Process:               Xcode [638]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0.1 (13249)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13249000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       823984564
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [638]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-10-19 10:45:48.831 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        FE2DA13F-B64C-DC82-FF55-0BE0D61794A9


Time Awake Since Boot: 940 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Comment: My will to help you not working, how to i fix it

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39603792/253056

Comment: @PaulR i will  download again

Comment: @PaulR i deleted deviredData but still not working

Comment: @Tiskender2: did you try the solution involving the .xib file in the linked question above ?

Comment: @PaulR i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran the package

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg.
```

And the Xcode 9 started to work.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall xcode just drag the xcode icon to the trash. Then you can reinstall it from the developers platform or through the regular download in the appstore.